# Upgrading Oracle forms and reports from 6i to 12c

Tags: oracle, migration, upgrade, oracleforms, oraclereports

We are planning a migration of an Oracle Forms and report 6i application to 12c, and at the same time we will upgrade to the latest version of Oracle (from 10g to 12c).

I would like to know the steps that we can follow, or from where to start?
Is there anything that we must consider before doing this? Any problems that we might encounter?

Any information whatsoever would be helpful !

Answer (score 1):

I just recently did this exact thing. 
You'll want to use the Forms migration assistant to do the heavy lifting. Copy your FMB files somewhere and run the assistant against them. Then open the FMB's in 12c and convert the 2 tier commands to 3 tier (like HOST to CLIENT_HOST (using webutil), etc) and you also may want to look for other enhancements that can be made using 12c specific code over 6i (file operation handling, reports, external link handling, etc)